# UIView Not Changing Size On Rotation Autolayout

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIScrollView` with a `UIView` for content inside of it.  On the `UIView`,  I have some buttons I'm using for a menu.  Everything works great until I rotate to landscape.  Once I rotate, the buttons on the `UIView` can't be clicked but the top buttons still work.  I'm assuming it's because the `UIView` holding the buttons isn't being resized so it's not responding to taps.  This can be seen in the 3d exploded image (Image 4).  I have tried all of these lines of code to try to get it to resize, buttons have worked (code is commented because I tried different combos).

```
override func willRotateToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval) {
    //hides and displays tab bar on orientation changes
    if toInterfaceOrientation.isLandscape {
        tabBarController!.tabBar.hidden = true


        //self.navigationController!.view.sizeToFit()
        //self.navigationController!.view.setNeedsLayout()
        //self.viewForContent.setNeedsLayout()
        //self.viewForMenuItems.setNeedsLayout()
        //self.viewForContent.contentSize = CGSizeMake(900, 900)
        //self.viewForContent.setNeedsLayout()     
    }
    else if toInterfaceOrientation.isPortrait {
        tabBarController!.tabBar.hidden = false

        //self.navigationController!.view.setNeedsLayout()
        //self.viewForContent.setNeedsLayout()
        //self.viewForMenuItems.setNeedsLayout()

        //self.viewForContent.contentSize = CGSizeMake(900, 900)
        //self.viewForContent.setNeedsLayout()

    }
}
```

Also I have this in the DidLoad and DidLayoutSubviews.  When I comment out the DidLayoutSubviews the buttons work again, but the scrollview isn't large enough to allow me to scroll to the bottom buttons when in landscape

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let size = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
    viewForContent.contentSize = CGSizeMake(size.width, 458)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    let size = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
    viewForContent.contentSize = CGSizeMake(size.width, 458)
}
```

The My Information, My Staff, My Colleagues, and My Residents are the buttons that work in landscape mode.

I have used `autolayout` constraints to setup the views.  Also, I am using `XCode7` with `Swift`.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You do know that `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` is deprecated, right?

Comment: First of all `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` is deprecated use `viewWillTransitionToSize`. The next thing is if you are using interface builder with auto layout you should not have to write the frame codes until and unless you need to override them. There must be auto layout problem. "https://iosschool.wordpress.com/2015/10/30/uiscrollview-with-autolayout/" this can be helpful

Answer (score 0):

First I setup my views as outlined in the link posted above in the comments by Kusul (Thank you).  But when I did this and added the buttons to the content view they wouldn't show on when the screen was rotated to landscape because they were off of the bottom and the UIScrollView didn't "grow".

I figured out that I needed to add a bottom constraint to my last button.  So the last button now has a constraint to the top and the bottom.  This forced the scroll view to "grow" to the proper size.  I could then eliminate setting the size in the didLoad and didLayoutSubviews. Thanks for the help